# Como guardar los datos de un XML en una tabla en SQL server usando VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, xml, sql-server-2012

estoy haciendo un programa en vb.net que consume un web service SOAP, y ejecuto un metodo que me devuelve un XML y lo almaceno en la variable element, quisiera saber como hago para guardar ese XML en forma de tabla en SQL SERVER, donde cada nodo del XML corresponde a un campo en la tabla sql. Mi codigo en vb.net es el siguiente :

```
Dim Service As New WS.Service
Dim key As String
Dim data As String
Dim officeList As String

key = Service.Logon("MyUser", "MyPass")
data = Service.GetOfficesCristian(key, officeList)
Dim element As XElement = XElement.Parse(data)
```

El xml generado es más o menos así:

```
<IEOffices>
 <Office>
  <ISOcode>RUS</ISOcode>
  <OfficeCode>1026201</OfficeCode>
  <OfficeName> "Uralsib" PAO , "Kuzbasskiy" F-la PAO "URALSIB" v</OfficeName>
  <Address>pr. Oktyabrskiy, 2</Address>
  <Phone>+7 (3842) 72-38-59, 72-28-65</Phone>
  <CityName>Kemerovo</CityName>
  <WorkingHours>&#x43F;&#x43D;-&#x43F;&#x442;: 09:00: 20:00, &#x441;&#x431;: 10:0016:00, 
   &#x432;&#x441;: &#x432;&#x44B;&#x445;&#x43E;&#x434;&#x43D;&#x43E;&#x439;</WorkingHours>
  <Agent>Zolotaya Korona </Agent>
  <Direction>B</Direction>
  <WorkingCurrency>RUR;USD;EUR;</WorkingCurrency>
</Office>
<Office>
  <ISOcode>RUS</ISOcode>
  <OfficeCode>966537</OfficeCode>
  <OfficeName> "URALSIB" PAO , "MEZHDURECHENSKIJ" F-LA PAO "URAL</OfficeName>
  <Address>PR-KT STROITELEJ, DOM 18</Address>
  <Phone>+7 (38475) 2-10-03, 2-17-67</Phone>
  <CityName>MEZHDURECHENSK</CityName>
  <WorkingHours>&#x43F;&#x43D;-&#x43F;&#x442;: 09:00-18:00, &#x441;&#x431;: 10:00-16:00, 
   &#x432;&#x441;: &#x432;&#x44B;&#x445;&#x43E;&#x434;&#x43D;&#x43E;&#x439;</WorkingHours>
  <Agent>Zolotaya Korona </Agent>
  <Direction>B</Direction>
  <WorkingCurrency>RUR;USD;EUR;</WorkingCurrency>
</Office>
</IEOffices>
```

Cada oficina "" representa un record en la tabla de sqlserver

La tabla ya esta creada, es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE PAYEES(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
ISOcode VARCHAR(5),
OfficeCode VARCHAR(20),
OfficeName NVARCHAR(30),
Address NVARCHAR(50),
Phone VARCHAR(20),
CityName VARCHAR(30),
WorkingHours NVARCHAR(40),
Agent VARCHAR(20),
Direction VARCHAR(3),
WorkingCurrency VARCHAR(20)
)
```

Comment: ¿Ya tienes la tabla creada? ¿Puedes mostrarnos el nombre de la tabla y los nombres y tipos de datos de las columnas?

Comment: Sí, la tabla ya esta creada, añadí el query de la creacion de la tabla

Comment: Vale, ¿cómo sueles insertar datos de VB en una tabla de SQL server? Hay un montón de opciones https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/accessing-data, ¿cuál de esas sueles utilizar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes convertir los datos de XML en objetos anonimos in VB (solo he mostrado dos attributos, puedes añadir el resto de la misma manera):

```
  For Each office In element.<Office>
        Dim row = New With {.ISOCode = office.<ISOcode>.Value, .OfficeCode = office.<OfficeCode>.Value}
        Console.WriteLine(row)
    Next
```

En lugar de Console.WriteLine(row) vas a insertar el objeto en tu tabla, cómo se hace esto depende del método de acesso que utilizas, con Entity Framework https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/ podrías crear las entidades en lugar de un objeto anonimo y simplemente añadarlas a tu contexto representando la tabla.